# Проверить друзей Vk Api

Tags: android, vkontakte-api

Можно как то через Api Vk проверить ,являются ли два разных пользователя друзьями? Проверял через метод `friends.areFriends`, но там проверяется только текущий пользователь.

Comment: Можно, получив список друзей одного из них. Одна проблема - эти данные пользователь может скрыть.

Comment: и как мне их сравнить, чтоб узнать , что они друзья?

Comment: У каждого пользователя есть уникальный идентификатор. Получаете список друзей для одного человека. Проверяете, есть ли идентификатор другого в списке. Это же просто проверка списка на вхождение элемента...